# Find particular pages having session timed out in google analytics

Tags: session, google-analytics

I want to find out the pages where user's session was timed out over a certain time frame (lets say 3 months). Is it possible with google analytics? 
I did some research on all the data present for particular pages but i couldn't get to the conclusion that on which pages user's get frequent time out and they are not able to save their data or may be they are not doing any activity on that page. 
PS: My application has session timeout set to 60 minutes.

Please suggest how should i proceed to get this kind of information.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you would need to send an event to Google Analytics when the session times out as follows:

`ga('send', 'event', 'Session', 'Timeout');`

In the above example the third and fourth parameters are the event category and action respectively and you can set the values to whatever you want. Then to get the report you want, you would navigate to the Behavior > Events > Top Events report in the GA interface and add a secondary dimension of `Page`. You will then be able to see all the pages where the session timeout occurred:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I do get the idea to get my session time outs with google analytics. It was not implemented in my application before. can i still be able to get some idea about the pages where session timed out? I tried to figure out combinations of different columns of Behaviour>Page reports but i couldn't establish any relation that can point me in the direction of session time out. I tried to get the information from session time,avg time on page,exits(exit page of session),%exits etc. But couldn't gather much information to lead to any decision

Comment: The best way to do this would be to use events as described above. If this is not feasible for you, then there may be other more subtle ways but it depends on what happens after a session times out. Does the user just see some sort of pop up or do they get redirected to a specific page? If they get redirected, you *may* be able to get some info using the behaviour flow report.